# What's the difference between "errand" and "issue" or "matter"?

Tags: word-usage, differences

I am a non-native English speaker. I want to apply for an annual leave to handle my personal [errand/issue/matter]. In my email, which word is more suitable? I've searched that "matter" might be the right word. But I still can see others using "errand". Can somebody tell me when to use errand other than else?

Comment: "Issue" and (in one sense) "matter" mean roughly the same thing.  If you look in a dictionary, though, you will see that the primary meaning of "errand" is different.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104899/personal-issue-private-issue-personal-affair-or-personal-business - This thread might be of interest to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["personal issue", "private issue", "personal affair", or "personal business"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104899/personal-issue-private-issue-personal-affair-or-personal-business)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, "issue" and "matter" are referring to something similar to a problem that needs to be taken care of, while "errand" is something that needs to be carried out and does not connote "problem" .

Comment: And "errand" implies an activity (at least figuratively physical), while the others do not.